# Pull a private repo as a dependency during a dokku deploy?

Tags: ssh, dependencies, dokku

I am using Dokku on DigitalOcean to deploy `my_app`.
My app has a dependency which points to a private repo `git@github.com:my_org/my_app.git`.

```
Step 10 : RUN <some_command_to_install_deps>
 ---> Running in ceada9d96c61
* Getting my_repo (git@github.com:my_org/my_app.git)
remote:  verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried adding deploy keys using https://github.com/cedricziel/dokku-deployment-keys to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the deployment keys plugin, you will also need the [hostkeys plugin](https://github.com/cedricziel/dokku-hostkeys-plugin) to add `github.com` to the container's `known_hosts` file. For example, to approve `github.com` across all applications on the machine, simply do...

Install the plugin...

```
dokku plugin:install https://github.com/cedricziel/dokku-hostkeys-plugin.git hostkeys-keys
```

Then run...

```
sudo dokku hostkeys:shared:autoadd github.com
```

If you still face issues after doing this, there is something wrong with your deployment keys setup. In that case, leave a comment and I'll help troubleshoot it

Comment: Hey, I am still having this issue, is there a way you can help me? This is the error I am getting 

"fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
       Confirm the import path was entered correctly."